# How do I configure BeyondCompare to ignore SCM replaced text in comments?

Tags: version-control, perforce, ignore, beyondcompare

I do have some text sequences that are replaced by the SCM (Perforce in my case).

I do want to configure BeyondCompare to consider these sequences as unimportant differences in order to be able to ignore them when I compare files.

In my case it's about Python source files and the sequences are looking like

```
# $Id: //depot/.../filename#7 $
# $DateTime: 2010/09/01 10:45:29 $
# $Author: username $
# $Change: 1234 $
```

Sometimes these sequences can be outside comments, but even in this cases I would like to be able ignore these lines because they are not really changed.

Comment: There used be a Compare By Rules options where you could say that comments were Unimportant Differences, however I just checked my version (3.1.9) and Compare By Rules seems to have been removed? At least, I cannot find it.
What version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beyond Compare's parser doesn't currently (v3/v4) support nested elements, so file formats grammars can't be used to mark an SCM sequence as unimportant for a specific file type if the text is already classified as a comment, string, etc.

Beyond Compare 4.0 added support for marking arbitrary text as unimportant across an entire comparison, separate from the grammar.

1. Load the files you're interested in
2. Click the **Session Settings** button (aka **Rules** w/ umpire icon) or use the **Session->Session Settings** menu item.
3. Switch to the **Importance tab**
4. Click the `+` button at the bottom of the **Unimportant text** list.
5. Add the plain text or regular expression to **Text to find** edit and check the **Regular Expression** checkbox if necessary.  In this case the regular expression would be:
   `\$(Id|DateTime|Author|Change):.*\$`
6. Click **Ok**.
7. By default these changes will only affect the current comparison.  You can change the combobox at the bottom of the Session Settings dialog from **Use for this view only** to **Also update session defaults** to make it affect all future comparisons for all file types.

Answer (score 16):

You need to define a new grammar element (let's call it "SCM") and mark it as unimportant ([see the tutorial here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3); choose "Basic" and make sure to check "Regular Expression").

The grammar element should be (if I interpret your examples correctly):

```
^.*\$(Id|DateTime|Author|Change):.*$
```

This will ignore any line that contains `$Id:`, `$DateTime:` etc.

If you only want to ignore lines that start with `# $...`, use

```
^\s*#s*\$(Id|DateTime|Author|Change):.*$
```

And if you only want to ignore stuff between `$` (and treat everything else as important), use

```
\$[^$\r\n]*\$
```

or

```
\$(Id|DateTime|Author|Change)[^$\r\n]*\$
```

depending on whether you care about those keywords or not.

Comment: I know that there is a small probability to mistake but aren't we supposed to ignore only the text between the $ signs on these lines?

Comment: In your examples, the lines only consist of text between `$` signs, preceded by a comment `#` which you said was not always there (although I can hardly imagine that). Can you provide more examples?

Comment: OK. I edited the answer. Hope I understand your requirements now.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. It seems that the comment grammar rule picks it up before the custom grammar. Is it possible to mark SCM element changes inside a comment as unimportant, while comment changes in general are still important?