# How do I make Beyond Compare ignore certain differences while comparing versions of Delphi Form Files

Tags: delphi, version-control, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I use Beyond Compare (version 3.1.10) to compare different versions of Delphi Form Files, but I don't want to see differences concerning ExplicitTop, ExplicitLeft, ExplicitHeight and ExplicitWidth.

Details:
These lines will always begin with a number of whitespace characters, then "ExplicitXXX = " and a number. Older versions of Delphi didn't have these lines, so I want to ignore differences where these lines are added to the newest version, and I also want to ignore differences where the number has changed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit:
Duplicate (more or less) of:

[How do I configure BeyondCompare to ignore SCM replaced text in comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652301/how-do-i-configure-beyondcompare-to-ignore-scm-replaced-text-in-comments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure BeyondCompare to ignore SCM replaced text in comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652301/how-do-i-configure-beyondcompare-to-ignore-scm-replaced-text-in-comments)

Comment: But with a better answer here IMO....

Comment: The other question is asking about matching text within other grammar items (comments, strings), and BC doesn't support nesting grammar items yet, so the solution here won't work there.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

1. Load a pair of DFM files showing the difference.
2. Click the **Session Settings** button (aka **Rules** w/ umpire icon) or use the **Session**->**Session Settings** menu item.
3. Switch to the **Importance** tab then click the **Edit Grammar...** button to open a second dialog.
4. Click the **New...** button below the top listbox to open a third dialog.
5. Change the **Element Name** option to something like `Explicit*`, change the **Text Matching** to `Explicit(Left|Top|Width|Height) = \d+` and check the **Match character case** and **Regular expression** checkboxes, then click **Ok**, then click **Ok** again in the second dialog.
6. `Explicit*` should now appear in the original dialog's **Grammar Elements** list.  Uncheck it, then change the combobox at the bottom of the dialog from **Use for this view only** to **Update session defaults**.

Comment: Fabolous answer, just what I was hoping for. You can't beat a good walkthrough :-)

Comment: Especially when it comes from the horse's mouth himself.

Comment: Note that these instructions describe how to define the given text as "Unimportant", which (by default) will still be visible (and colored blue). You can ignore/hide Blue text with the "Ignore Unimportant Differences" toggle.

Comment: For more recent versions: http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3   btw if you could right click in a code file compare and apply for ex. a namespace difference as unimportant for that session (to apply to all code comparisons) that would be so sweet.

Answer (score 9):

I don't use Beyond Compare, but if you want to have newer versions of Delphi stop adding the (IMO useless) `Explicit*` properties, you can use Andreas Hausladen's [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=10)

Comment: +1. I installed DDevExtensions some time ago to get rid of these properties and didn't regret it up to now.

Comment: That's part of the problem. Some of the developers on my team use this extension, others do not.

Comment: @Svein: Can't you convince them that the Explicit* stuff is more than superfluous?

Comment: @Ulrich: I suppose, but it still doesn't answer the actual question. And in addition to the explicit values I would like to do the same thing with the ActivePage property of page controls, so I would like to find a solution to that also.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (C#), I wanted to ignore the entire line which contained namespaces (and thus, using's) which I changed.
([Referenced Walkthrough - Ignore entire line if text exist in line](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=4510)

ie.

```
namespace INSERT.NAMESPACE.HERE 
      changed to 
namespace INSERT.NAMESPACE.HERE.NEW
```

To do that

In step 5. of Craig's solution, change the **Text Matching** to

```
" .\*INSERT.NAMESPACE.HERE.\* "
```

(include the quotes)

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Craig Peterson's answer is correct. 
N.B. However! The tab 'importance' is not always visible from Session/Session-settings. Always, from inside a Folder list view, it will not be there. It seems there are certain filetypes that do not have it either, though I'm less clear on that. BC has so many options and plugins I bet there is a workaround, but for me I have been ok so far.
http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=8457