# Ignore non UTF-8 characters in Beyond Compare

Tags: utf-8, comparison, diff, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

My project include some units of measurement that are expressed with non UTF-8 characters like the squared symbol. With most editors these are displayed with the following character: �.

I am comparing parts of the source code with `beyond compare` and I would like to ignore the cases where these symbol appear. I tried with these two solutions:

[Beyond Compare - ignore certain text strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171486/beyond-compare-ignore-certain-text-strings)

[How do I make Beyond Compare ignore certain differences while comparing versions of Delphi Form Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668439/how-do-i-make-beyond-compare-ignore-certain-differences-while-comparing-versions)

but in both cases the differences are still marked in red (? vs � or ² vs �). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the characters are unprintable characters, you can define them as unimportant text in Beyond Compare 4's Text Compare using a hex value.

As an example, assume the character is superscript 2, the squared symbol, with hex value 0x00B2.

1. Load files in the Text Compare.
2. Click the Rules toolbar button (referee icon).
3. In the Importance tab, click Edit Grammar.
4. In the Grammar tab, click +.
5. Element name: Squared
6. Text matching: \x{00B2}
7. Check Regular Expression
8. Click OK.
9. Click OK.
10. In the Grammar element list, uncheck Squared to make it unimportant.
11. Click OK.

If **View | Ignore Unimportant Text** is turned on, differences matching Squared will show as a match (black). If it is turned off, differences matching matching Squared will show in blue.

In the above instructions, the regular expression \x{nnnn} matches on character with hex value nnnn.

References:

[Unicode Character Superscript 2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)

[Define Unimportant Text in Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3)

[Beyond Compare Help - Regular Expression Reference](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?regular_expression_reference.html)

Comment: Ok, I actually managed to make the symbol display in black or blue, according to the flag "ignore unimportant differences". However there's still a red line on the cursor where the symbol appears. Is there a way to truly ignore these type of differences.

Comment: A screen shot of the problem and a pair of example files might be needed to diagnose this issue. If you don't want to post them publicly, email them to support@scootersoftware.com with a link to this page and we'll investigate.