# How to correctly enter differences to be ignored by Beyond Compare

Tags: beyondcompare4

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668439/how-do-i-make-beyond-compare-ignore-certain-differences-while-comparing-versions) on how to add rules to a certain or self specified file types to enable ignoring certain differences. I don't seem to understand how it works exactly and I couldn't find anything helping on the web.

Consider the following example:
I have an XML document in which `<abc attr="foo">content</abc>` and `<xyz attr="foo">content</xyz>` are matched as a different. I want to ignore this difference since it is unimportant. I go to **Session** > **Session Settings** switch to **Importance Tab** and click on **Edit Grammar...** (all on my desired file format derived from XML format I created and selected previously). I then add a new Rule using **New...**. I choose **Text Matching** and check **Match character case** as well as **Regular expression**. I tried several different versions for this rule:

- `<abc.*`
- `(<abc|<xyz).*`
- `<abc.*|<xyz.*`

I also tried to add two rules with settings mentioned above where one matched on `<abc.*` and the other on `<xyz.*`.

But none of these rules worked. I unchecked the rule(s) on **Session Settings** and let Beyond Compare ignore unimportant differences but the lines I expected to vanish from the diff now didn't disappear. They persisted and I don't seem to be able to get rid of them.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I found the solution. The correct rule is:

`<(abc|xyz) attr="foo">content</(abc|xyz)>`